# Change Google Sign in Pop URL

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am hosting [my firebase app](https://www.crowdform.co.uk/hntv) on the path `/hntv` and the custom domain `www.crowdform.co.uk`.

Using `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(...)` works when my `authDomain` is configured to `hacker-news-tv.firebaseapp.com`.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  authDomain: 'hacker-news-tv.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'hacker-news-tv',
  ...
}
```

However, incognito and browsers that [block 3rd parties](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/865) aren't able to signin. The fix is to change the `authDomain` to  my custom domain

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    authDomain: 'www.crowdform.co.uk',
    projectId: 'hacker-news-tv',
    ...
  }
```

However, the popurl opens at

https://www.crowdform.co.uk/__/auth/handler

Which doesn't every get forwarded to the firebase app as it is hosted at https://www.crowdform.co.uk/hntv is there any way I can modify this pop URL?

Comment: Why did you set it up to forward to a custom path?

Comment: Because the main website is something totally unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the [redirect_uri here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials). [More detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39065422/1376627)